# Show that if a self-adjoint matrix is triangular, then it must be diagonal.

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to show that if a self-adjoint matrix is triangular, then it must be diagonal.

Here's my thoughts so far:

Self adjoint is simply $\langle A \pmb x, \pmb y \rangle = \langle \pmb x, A \pmb y\rangle$

If $A$ is lower triangular then $\langle \pmb b, \pmb y \rangle = \langle \pmb x , \pmb c\rangle$ where

$$
\pmb b = \begin{bmatrix}a_{11}x_1 \\ a_{21} x_2 + a_{22} x_2 \\ \vdots \\ \sum_{i=1}^n a_n x_i\end{bmatrix}
$$

We don't really know anything about $\pmb c$ beyond that $A \pmb y = \pmb c$ and the equality shown above.

Intuitively, I want to think of the inner product as being characterized by the identity matrix because then I'd have a straightforward system of equations that would show that $A$ must only have entries along the diagonal...

Another thought is to somehow show that $A$ must be both upper and lower triangular to be self-adjoint which would imply it's diagonal.

I'm not sure how to advance from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Take $x$ to be the standard basic vector $e_i$ and $y$ to be the standard basic vector $e_j$. So $\langle e_i, Ae_j\rangle=\langle Ae_i, e_j\rangle$. This should give you some info about the matrix $A$.

Comment: $Ae_j$ would be some column of $A$ but I'm still not sure how that'd help me compare things across the inner product...

Comment: True, $Ae_j$ is the $j$-th column of $A$. Then $\langle e_i, Ae_j\rangle$ is the entry $A_{i,j}$. And the equality for every $i,j$ means that $A_{i,j}=A_{j,i}$, so $A$ is symmetric. Symmetric and triangular means diagonal.

Comment: I don't think $\langle e_i, Ae_j \rangle$ is the $A_{i,j}$ entry unless we know that the inner product is characterized by the identity matrix. Wouldn't this mess things up if we had a permutation matrix or weighted inner product?

Comment: @financial_physician: The dot product in the OP is standard. If we "mess things up", we would also have to "mess up" the standard basic vectors $e_i$, and change $A$ accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that with the standard inner product, the adjoint of a matrix $A$ is given by the transpose $^tA$ (or conjugate transpose if you are using $\mathbb C^n$ rather than $\mathbb R^n$).

Comment: But checking isn't sufficient is it? I need to do it more generally

Comment: By "check" I meant it's something you can prove in general without too much trouble